# Multiple classifier comparison with Bayesian statistics

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-bayesian, method-comparison

I've been recently working on some classifier comparisons. I've come to realize, the critical distance diagrams introduced $\approx$ 10 years ago might not be the most relevant solution for this problem.

[Statistical Comparisons of Classifiers
over Multiple Data Sets](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf)

Are there any Python-based packages which solve multiple classifier comparisons via Bayesian sampling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using Bayesiantests package, which leverages pystan for the sampling scheme.